# How can I export a react material-ui component with 2 styles object? (material-ui V1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

We are using material-ui v1 and to compose HOC we are using recompose utility. The problem is we have 2 styles object. One is defined inside the component and other is general style object (defined in another jsx style file which exports javascript style objects that is being used system-wide). Now we need to compose both styles object. Is there any way to do that? **composing 2 style objects with withStyles does not work.** Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Here is our code:**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { generalStyle } from '../../modules/styles/styles';//external style object

//internal style object
const styleObj = theme => ({
  paper: {
    padding: 16,
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
});

class myCompo extends React.Component {
//..compo code
}

//composing 2 style objects with withStyles does not work
export default compose(
  withStyles({ styleObj, generalStyle }),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(myCompo );

//here is how generalStyle is defined in styles.jsx file
const generalStyle = theme => ({
  floatR: {
    float: 'right',
  },
  floatL: {
    float: 'left',
  },
  parallelItmes: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing.unit,
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit + 10,
  },
});

module.exports = {
  generalStyle,
};
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you can try `export default compose(
  withStyles({ styleObj }),
  withStyles({ generalStyle }),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(myCompo );`

Comment: Thank you Subham for the reply. I had already tried that and it shows this warning message in red: Warning: Material-UI: the key `paper` provided to the classes property is not implemented in Connect(myCompo).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't take `generalStyle` and merge it into the interal style object with the spread operator (i.e., `...generalStyle`)? That would effectively allow you to use both styles everywhere you need to.

Comment: Thank you Jules for the reply. I tried spreading the gerealStyle but it did not work. Maybe I was doing wrong. This is how I tried to do it :`const styleObj = theme => ({
  ...generalStyle,
  paper: { //rest of style `. Can you please answer the question by showing me the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have `generalyStyles` defined something like this:

```
const generalStyles = theme => ({
  generalStylesButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});
```

Then, you can merge `generalStyles` into your `internalStyles` by executing the function (I think this is what you're missing based on your code snippet in the comments) and then spreading the resulting object:

```
const internalStyles = theme => ({
  internalStylesButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#00ff00",
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  // Notice that since generalStyles is a function, not an object, you need
  // to execute it before you can merge
  ...generalStyles(theme)
});
```

Then the styling from both sets of styles will be available:

```
function FlatButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Button className={classes.internalStylesButton}>
        Styled from internal
      </Button>
      <Button className={classes.generalStylesButton}>
        Styled from general
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

FlatButtons.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(internalStyles)(FlatButtons);
```

You can probably encapsulate this logic in an HOC to avoid duplicating the spread operator in each of your components. You probably also need to be careful about cases where `generalStyles` and `internalStyles` both have the same class names:

```
const general = theme => ({
  duplicateName: {
    backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
  },
});

const internal = theme => ({
  duplicateName: {
    backgroundColor: "#00ff00",
  },
  ...general(theme),
});
```

Having the spread operator reconcile `duplicateName` between these two styles might lead to tricky situations.